# boost::program_options: how to ignore unknown parameters?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

In the `boost::program_options` library, I cannot understand how to allow the user to pass a parameter which has not been added through `add_options()`.
I would like it to be just ignored, instead of terminating the program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem tonight. @TAS's answer put me on the right path, but it still took 20 minutes of finger-mumbling to figure out the exact syntax for my particular use case.

To ignore unknown options, instead of writing this:

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

I wrote this:

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).allow_unregistered().run(), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

Note that only the *middle* line is different.

In a nutshell, use `commandline_parser()` rather than `parse_commandline()`, with some 'dangly bits' (i.e., `.options(desc).allow_unregistered().run()`) tacked on after the invocation.

Answer (score 12):

From the boost::program_options documentation [How To: Allowing Unknown Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp120114352)

```
parsed_options parsed = 
    command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).allow_unregistered().run();
```